# Setting WebGL vertexAttribPointer after loading mesh: why is a delay required?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a web page which renders a 3d-model in a viewport using WebGL, and I'm confused as to why a delay is required after I load a 3d model. The 3d-model is an .OBJ file and I use a library (K3D.js) for loading & parsing .OBJ files.

I realize that the file has to be loaded asynchronously into the browser. But as far as I understand, the library handles that part. Here's what the K3D load function looks like:

```
K3D.load = function(path, resp)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", path, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function(e){resp(e.target.response);};
    request.send();
}
```

So when K3D finishes loading the file, it presumably executes the function stored in `request.onload` , which I supply in my Mesh class (in the `meshFromOBJ` method):

```
Mesh.prototype.meshFromArray = function( vertexArray, normalArray ) {
    this.vbo = this.gl.createBuffer();
            //normals are left out for now
    this.numVertices = vertexArray.length / 3.0;
    this.gl.bindBuffer( this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo );
    this.gl.bufferData( this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
        new Float32Array( vertexArray ), 
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW 
    );
    this.gl.bindBuffer( this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
};

Mesh.prototype.meshFromOBJ = function( file ) {

    var that = this;

    var loader = function( data ) {
        var model = K3D.parse.fromOBJ( data );
        var array = K3D.edit.unwrap( model.i_verts, model.c_verts, 3 );
        var norms = K3D.edit.unwrap( model.i_norms, model.c_norms, 3 );
        that.meshFromArray( array, model.c_norms );
    }

    K3D.load( file, loader );
};
```

In my main script I load the mesh, and set up vertex attribute pointers. I noticed that I had to place an alert between loading the mesh and setting the pointers, or else the browser would throw, amongst others, the `vertexAttribPointer: must have valid GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding` error. The relevant section of my script:

```
        mesh = new ngl.Mesh( webgl );
        mesh.meshFromOBJ( "cow.obj" );
        //set the vertex attribute pointer with a delay
        //otherwise, the mesh doesn't seem to exist yet :S
        setTimeout( function() {
            mesh.bind();
            webgl.vertexAttribPointer( program.attribute( "vert" ), 
                3, webgl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0 
            );
            mesh.unbind();
        }, 10 );
```

Why is the delay required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow time for the ajax request to complete. Rather than use some arbitrary time delay, you should be continuing execution once the request is complete. What if the request takes longer than 10ms to complete? Simple, your code blows-up. I.e K3D's request.onload fires *after* K3D has completed.

From a glance, fixing your code to remove the delay should be as simple as putting the following functionality *inside* your `loader` function.

```
mesh.bind();
webgl.vertexAttribPointer( program.attribute( "vert" ),3, webgl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0);
mesh.unbind();
```

Since you may wish to do different things with each mesh after they're loaded, it may make more sense for you to specify a function to be called after `that.meshFromArray` has completed.

I.e

```
Mesh.prototype.meshFromOBJ = function( file, whatToDoWhenMeshMade ) {

    var that = this;

    var loader = function( data ) {
        var model = K3D.parse.fromOBJ( data );
        var array = K3D.edit.unwrap( model.i_verts, model.c_verts, 3 );
        var norms = K3D.edit.unwrap( model.i_norms, model.c_norms, 3 );
        that.meshFromArray( array, model.c_norms );
        if (whatToDoWhenMeshMade != undefined)
            whatToDoWhenMeshMade(that);
    }

    K3D.load( file, loader );
};

function setupVertAttribPointer(meshObj)
{
    mesh.bind();
    webgl.vertexAttribPointer( program.attribute( "vert" ), 3, webgl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0);
    mesh.unbind();
}
```

// Finally, usage

```
mesh = new ngl.Mesh( webgl );
mesh.meshFromOBJ( "cow.obj",  setupVertAttribPointer);
```

So, `meshFromObj` will call `K3D.load`, which will initiate the ajax request. When the request completes, `meshFromObj.loader` will fire. Just before that returns, `setupVertAttribPointer` will run.

If you add some code to print to the console (1) immediately following `mesh.meshFromObj("cow.obj", setupVertAttribPointer);` and (2) as the last line of `setupVertAttribPointer`, which one do you now think will print first? If you answered (1) then my job of explaining what the A in ajax stands for is complete. If you answered (2), you should find a good ajax tutorial.